# update wso2 deployment.toml configuration at the docker runtime

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I am new to docker.
I can create image using dockerfile and successfully call WSO2-API

I have hardcoded configuration in deployment.toml file
I want to update this information at the docker runtime for different env - DEV,QA etc

deployment.toml file content -

```
[server]
offset = 22
```

How to update .toml file config at the runtime ?

https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.2.0/micro-integrator/setup/dynamic_server_configurations/#environment-variables

Here it says you can mention like-

offset = "${VariableName}"

but what do I mention in my dockerfile to update these variables at runtime ?

Comment: what do you mean by `update these variables at runtime`?

Comment: @gusto2 I have updated my answer above , I want different offset for different env. If I hardcode offset value , I can build the image successfully. I want to update this offset when I do my Kubernetes deployment. What changes do I have do do in docker file/Kubernetes configs for this ? Let me know if you need more Information. your help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to update this information at the docker runtime for different env - DEV,QA etc

There are multiple ways to achieve this, here are at least two we commonly use in our deployment

**Using a template for the config files**

Basically the idea is to mount the deployment.toml (or other config files / folders) as configmap values in Kubernetes or volume in pure docker.

For each environment you can template the configuration using any deployment tool (Maven, Puppet, Ansible, any cloud devops,...). This approach allows you to update the configuration templates without needing a new image.

**Template the configuration in the entrypoint**

Create an entrypoint script, which templates the configuration based on env variables  - e. g. using the `sed` utility) and then starts the application. Then use that entrypoint in the Dockerfile

This approach doesn't need external configuration (volumes, templates) but if the template needs to be updated, you need a new image.

Edit:

I haven't seen using the env variables in the deployment.toml before as refered in the question, must be something new for wso2. But if it is supported, then it can make your life easier just to specify the env variables in the pod. (oh this is you may be missing)

- specify the ENV value in the Dockerfile for the default value
- run the docker with your defined value (`-e` parameter for pure docker or defined environment in the compose or deployment config)

Answer (score 0):

Define the Variable using ARG option in Dockerfile.
Example:

ARG **VariableName**

Now the value can be given at runtime as below.

docker build --build-arg **VariableName=0** .

For more details on how to use ARG in dockerfile, please refer https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg